# How to check if the value of BigDecimal field is negative in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am getting some strange negative values in my report, which could be from the database. I want to format fields to display zero when the values are negative in the expression editor. How can this be done?

Comment: Expression will be like this: `$F{bigDecimalValue}.signum() == -1 ? "0" : "something else"`

Comment: @AlexK thanks, that solved it. But when I tried it on a Double value I got an error  `the method signum() is undefined for the type Double`

Comment: Okay, I got it `$V{doubleValue}  < 0 ? "0" : "something else"`

Answer (score 3):

You should use the *[BigDecimal.signum()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#signum())* method for check the sign of *BigDecimal*.

The expression will be:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{bigDecimalValue}.signum() == -1 ? "0" : "Not negative big decimal"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

The expression for *Double* is simpler:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doubleValue} < 0 ? "0" : "Non negative double"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

The sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="BigDecimal check" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="doubleValue" class="java.lang.Double" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[1234.567]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="bigDecimalValue" class="java.math.BigDecimal" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(-9.8)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="70">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="300" height="15"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doubleValue} < 0.0 ? "0" : "Non negative double"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="25" width="300" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{bigDecimalValue}.signum() == -1 ? "0" : "Not negative big decimal"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The output result generated in *Jaspersoft Studio* will be:

[image]